# java startup option "-Xmx512M -XX:MaxPerSize=1024M" doesn't work for my jvm

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, dump

I'm using oracle jdk1.8 on win10, trying to set max heap size of JVM and see what happens when OOM. Using this code snippet:

```
package mygroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class App 
{
    public static class AUser{
        private String name;
        private String gender;
        private int age;
        public AUser(String n,String g,int a){
            name=n;
            gender=g;
            age=a;
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println( "App!" );
        List<AUser> users=new ArrayList<AUser>();
        int max=40960000;
        int c=0;
        while(c < max){
            ++c;
            users.add(new AUser("Me","male",35));
        }
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

I compile and run it with

```
java mygroup/App -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPerSize=1024M
```

I expect that before it hits "System.in.read()", it should crash and report OOM error for JVM. But nothing happened. Acturally it runs normally, and wait for my key strike.

Then I started java visualVM, connect to "mygroup.App", and executed "heap dump". I could see that this JVM is using around 3.8G memory and totally 40960000 instances of "mygroup.App@AUser" is using 1.47G of memory.

Seems that "-Xmx512M -XX:MaxPerSize=1024M" is not working.

And if I change my program to

```
        while(true){
            users.add(new AUser("Me","male",35));
        }
```

to create objects, actually this program will run until there's no more memory of my machine(I have 16G memory!)

So how to make "max heap size" work?
Thansk!

Comment: Does `java -Xmx512M --XX:MaxPerSize=1024M mygroup.App` work? (i.e., put the _JVM arguments_ before the main class; otherwise, I believe they're being interpreted as _application arguments_)

Comment: There is no `-XX:MaxPerSize` option. There used to be a `-XX:MaxPermSize` (note the **m**) prior to Java 8. But trying to set it to a higher value than the total maximum heap size just specified via `-Xmx` never made sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM arguments need to go *before* the class you're running, as Slaw pointed out in a comment above.

Here's a really simple program, all it does it print out whatever string data was sent to the program as input parameters:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("arguments: " + Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```

Here are a few runs showing that everything *after* `example.java` is simply passed into the program as input arguments:

```
$ java example.java
arguments: []

$ java example.java one two three
arguments: [one, two, three]
```

Here's a variation identical to what you posted, with your intended JVM arguments isntead being treated as regular input parameters to the program:

```
$ java example.java -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPerSize=1024M
arguments: [-Xmx512M, -XX:MaxPerSize=1024M]
```

So, you'll want to re-order the command input to set JVM parameters instead of sending input parameters to your program.

Comment: Thanks, now I use command line "java -Xmx512M mygroup/App" to run it, it runs but hangs inside while loop and doesn't report OOM. My windows task manager show that this jvm is taking up 80% cpu rounds(I've 4 cores). So what's happening here, how to make OOM happen?

Comment: I am able to run your code like this: `java -Xmx1G App.java` - and after a few seconds it throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`; this is using OpenJDK 17.0.1. So, I'm not sure what's happening on your machine. It would be best to start a new question that focuses specifically on this - what you've tried, what you expected, what it's doing instead, etc.

Comment: @Troskyvs GC might be busy performing garbage collection. It should eventually throw OOM - you can see something like "GC overhead limit exceeded" in this case. Also note that _permanent generation_ area has been removed a long time ago so the flag `-XX:MaxPermSize` no longer works with modern JDKs (8 or later): https://chriswhocodes.com/hotspot_options_openjdk7.html?s=MaxPermSize